# Assigning rank to a date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following 2 columns in my data and I want to assign a rank to the date:

[image]

The rank column basically ranks assigns a number from the newest date to the oldest date. There might be duplicate dates so I need to look at the latest date in the "insert" column.

If you don't understand my question or need clarification, please give me a chance to improve my question before flagging it. I am new to sql and I really like this website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by col1 order by validfrom desc, insertdatetime desc) as rank
```

Comment: No this doesnt work. I have 8 rows in my data and now its turned into 53 rows.

Comment: @sam . . . `row_number()` does not increase the number of rows in the result set.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `window function`. Such as `dense_rank`:
first_column - column with values (Cust_A,Cust_B)

```
select *, dense_rank() over (partition by first_column order by ValidTo desc, ValidFrom desc,InsertDateTime desc) as rank
```

Comment: No it still didnt work for me. It did reduce my rows from 53 to 8. But 2020-03-01 is still not showing up as rank 1

Answer (score 0):

dense_rank() over (partition by customerid order by analyticsValueValidFrom desc, insertdatetime desc) as rank

Stupid me. I combined And #1 + Ans #2. This worked.